# Need to get the hourly count of product code grouped by batch code

Tags: sql, oracle

*my_table*

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| date_time          | batch_code_1 | batch_code_2 | prod_code |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 0:15:11 | X55          | D78          | 100 200   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 0:18:11 | D78          |              | 200       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 1:12:11 | X55          |              | 100       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 1:21:11 | X55          | D78          | 100 200   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 1:56:11 | X55          | D78          | 100 200   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 1:56:11 | D78          |              | 200       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Need to get the hourly count of product code grouped by batch code.

**expected output**

```
--------------------------------------------
| ON_HOUR       | BATCH_CODE | TOTAL_COUNT |
--------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 00 | D78        | 2           |
--------------------------------------------
| 2018/02/15 01 | D78        | 3           |
--------------------------------------------
```

**query using**

```
SELECT to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS on_hour,
     tab.batch_code_1 AS batch_code_1,
     tab.batch_code_2 AS batch_code_2,
     COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM   my_table tab
WHERE  date_time BETWEEN to_date('20180220000000', 'yyyymmddhh24miss') AND to_date('20180220235959', 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
AND    prod_code LIKE '%200%'
AND    (batch_code_1 = 'D78' OR batch_code_2 = 'D78')
GROUP  BY to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'),
        tab.batch_code_1,
        tab.batch_code_2
ORDER  BY to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') ASC;
```

But this query is not giving me teh desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick for your expected output is to considering :

```
nvl(tab.batch_code_2,batch_code_1) = 'D78'
```

and making your query as :

```
SELECT to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') on_hour,
   nvl(tab.batch_code_2,batch_code_1) batch_code,
   COUNT(1) total_count
  FROM  my_table tab
 WHERE  prod_code LIKE '%200%'
   AND  nvl(tab.batch_code_2,batch_code_1) = 'D78'
 GROUP  BY to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'), nvl(tab.batch_code_2,batch_code_1)
 ORDER  BY to_char(tab.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24');
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d255/1)

Comment: Is there any function like NVL in which i can use more than 2 arguments? Like I may have batch_code_1, batch_code_2...batch_code_n.

Comment: @Sushovon as far as i understand, you mean `decode` function which can be used for multi-variables.